# Full height sections single page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a responsive web site using Bootstrap.

The page is simple, yet there is a need for different sections on the same page, each section having a height of 100% screen height, så linking to a section anchor displays that section in 100% height and width. Width is no problem, but having multiple instances of height doesn't stack. Any tips on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution - put this inside a jQuery score where you listen on resizing/load events.

```
$('page').css('min-height',$(window).height()+'px');
```

Where page is the div section you whish to target.