# Shopify Single Static Section Fill Page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

When using a single section in Shopify how can you grow the div to fill the whole screen?

I have modified the `theme.scss file` and added a class

```
.hero--dsfull {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Butt the section needs to FILL the window not just the `div` it is in.

See Example: https://bunc.bike/pages/test

[Screenshot showing white space to be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX5ik.png)

I came across a potential solution but I do not know how to implement it:
[Full height sections single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036836/full-height-sections-single-page)

Comment: What theme did you use? Is your theme isn't that feature?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to that `/pages/test` page only then do like this.

```
<div class="page-container {% if page.url == '/pages/test' %}full-height{% endif %}" id="PageContainer"></div>
```

Add below `SCSS` code in your `theme.scss.liquid` file

```
.page-container{
    &.full-height{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

**OR**

Add below code in `template.liquid` or `page.liquid` file.

```
{% if page.url == '/pages/test' %}
<style type="text/css">
    .page-container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
{% endif %}
```

This solution for specific `page` based on `page.url` not for global/all-pages solution.

[image]

> **Hope this will help you!**